# Bit order in python's struct.pack

Tags: python, struct, endianness

When packing bytes with python's struct.pack, I was surprised that although my **byte** order is little-endian, my **bit** order appears to be big-endian. My most significant bytes appear on the right side in the output below, but the most significant bits of each byte appear on the left. (I'm using BitArray from [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring) to display the bits.)

```
In[23]: BitArray(struct.pack('B', 1)).bin
Out[23]:'00000001'
In[24]: BitArray(struct.pack('H', 1)).bin
Out[24]:'0000000100000000'
In[25]: sys.byteorder
Out[25]:'little'
```

This surprises me because I read [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6788) that "Bit order usually follows the same endianness as the byte order for a given computer system. That is, in a big endian system the most significant bit is stored at the lowest bit address; in a little endian system, the least significant bit is stored at the lowest bit address."

Am I interpreting it correctly that my bit order is the reverse of my byte order here?

Also, I know you can change the byte order using the `>` and `<`, but I guess there is no way to change the bit order?

**Edit:** For context, right now I'm writing a python implementation of TCP communication with an ATI NetFT sensor based on the protocol description starting on page B - 76 [here](https://www.ati-ia.com/app_content/documents/9610-05-1022.pdf). But, this same question comes up frequently in my work implementing serial and network communications with all sorts of sensors. In this case, the protocol description says things like: set bit 2 of byte 16 to 1 to bias the sensor, and I've been finding that bit 0 in python does not correspond to the bit 0 that controls the bias -- the bit order in the byte seems to be flipped.

Comment: If it's flipped in Python, it'll be flipped in C or anywhere else. Would seem like a good time to talk to whoever wrote the documentation for your sensor.

Answer (score 5):

No, Python supplies no way to reverse the bit order - but you don't need to.  The article made you overly paranoid ;-)

The endianness of byte order is *normally* invisible to software.  If, e.g., you read a 2-byte short in C, the underlying hardware delivers a big-endian result regardless of the physical storage convention.  Store 258 (0x0102) and you read 258 back, regardless of the storage's physical byte order.  The only way you can tell the difference is to read (or write) part of an N-byte value in a chunk of less than N bytes.  That's common enough in network protocols and portable storage formats, but rare outside those.

Similarly, the only way you *could* detect the endianness of physical bit order is if the machine were bit-addressable, so you could read one bit at a time directly.  I don't know of any current machine that supports bit addressing, and even if there were such a beast C supports no direct bit-level access anyway.  If you read a byte at time, the hardware will deliver the bytes in big-endian bit order again regardless of the physical bit storage order.

If, e.g., you're poking a bit at a time into a bit-level serial port, then you'll need to know the convention the specific hardware requires.  But in that case `struct.pack()` is useless anyway - the smallest unit `struct.pack()` manipulates is a byte, and at *that* level hardware bit-level ordering is invisible.  For example, your `struct.pack('B', 1)` will unpack as 1 regardless of the bit-level endianness of the machine you run it on.

### Bits of Code

Since "general principles" don't seem to be enough here, and there was no specific code presented to work with, here are bits of code that may be useful.

As mentioned in a comment, if you want to reverse a byte's bit order, the simplest and fastest way is to precompute a list with 256 items, mapping a byte to its bit-reversed value:

```
br = [int("{:08b}".format(i)[::-1], 2) for i in range(256)]
assert sorted(br) == list(range(256))
```

Then, e.g.,

```
>>> br[0], br[1], br[2], br[254], br[255]
(0, 128, 64, 127, 255)
```

If you're working with `bytes` objects, the `.translate()` method can use this table (after converting it to a `bytes` object) to convert the whole object with one call:

```
reverse_table = bytes(br)
```

and then, e.g.,

```
>>> original = bytes([0, 1, 2, 3, 254, 255])
>>> print([i for i in original.translate(reverse_table)])
[0, 128, 64, 192, 127, 255]
```

If instead you're building bytes a bit at a time (as in "set bit 2 of byte 16 to 1"), you can build them in "reversed order" (when appropriate) from the start.  To build a byte in `LSB 0` order, "setting bit i" means

```
byte |= 1 << i
```

To build a byte in `MSB 0` order instead, it's

```
byte |= 1 << (7-i)
```

But without knowing the precise details of the API(s) you're using, and how you like to work, it's really not possible to guess at the precise code you need.

Comment: On the communication of network, how an [LSB 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) host could correctly interpret data send by an MSB 0 host?

Comment: @Tim Peters, thanks for your contribution. I've added more context to my question. I have to say though, that you appear to be attempting to convince me I don't want my question answered rather than attempting to provide an answer! This is very common on SO...

Comment: @georgexsh, Yes, I think that's the question I'm trying to ask!

Comment: @foobarbecue, I did answer the question you asked ;-)  Python supplies no direct way to reverse the bits, _or_ to detect the bit ordering in use, for reasons already explained in some detail.  If you're mucking with hardware at the bit level, "you'll need to know the convention the specific hardware requires".  It's also common on SO for someone to dismiss an answer when it's not what they want to hear ;-)

Comment: If you know the convention, then you can precompute a list to reverse bits yourself; e.g., `br[0] = 0, br[1] = 128, br[2] = 64, ..., br[255] = 255`.  Then `br[byte]` retrieves the byte with its bits reversed.  It's possible that pySerial could also be useful to you https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Comment: @TimPeters how about my question, would you like to explain it a little bit?

Comment: @georgexsh, _all_ integer types in Python appear to be `LSB 0`, regardless of the platform you're running on, and regardless of whether the integer takes 8 bits or a billion bits to represent.  Likewise for C.  So if you're in a context where you need, e.g., the least significant bit to have weight `2**7` instead of `2**0`, then you need to write code to make that happen.  If you don't know how to do that, then ask a very specific question, showing both specific inputs and the specific outputs you want.

Comment: @TimPeters, I've upvoted your answer now that it includes useful stuff on bit order. I'm going to wait to accept any answers until I fully understand what's going on with this sensor. It may just be a semantic matter of how the manual was written.

Comment: @foobarbecue, it may help if you included some of the _actual code_ you're using, showing both what it does now and what you want it to do instead.  If you think it's hard for you to understand what's going on with the sensor, imagine what it's like for us - we have neither the sensor nor a single line of the troublesome code to look at ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Thanks for your explanation, but I still confuse will wire transfer, it seems all "high level" protocols have an agreement, to encoding in LSB 0 bit order. For example, there is no mention of bit order in [protobuf spec](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure), but the example shows it using LSB 0.

Comment: When data are serialised for transmission the bits must indeed be in the order defined by the communication standard, otherwise one system could reverse the bit order of received bytes. Since bytes are stored in parallel, there is no inherent "bit order". All you need to know is that `some_int & 1` will always give you the lowest order bit of `some_int`.